# Sorting 10GB Data in 1 GB memory. How will I do it?

Tags: algorithm

Here is the problem:
I have only 1GB RAM in computer. I have a text file of 10 GB data.This file contains numbers. How will I sort them?

Adding some more details.

```
 -They are all integers like 10000, 16723998 etc.   
 -same integer values can be repeatedly appearing in the file.
```

Comment: How big are the numbers?  Are they integers, or arbitrary-precision?  What format are they in?  This is an interesting puzzle, but it's missing some details.

Comment: It's still not clear what the file format is. Are the integers signed 32-bit and written out in base 10 separated by nulls (\u0000)? Unsigned 64-bit packed in 8 bytes each? Also, how much scratch space is available on disk?

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming puzzle of any kind, as this is a standard problem (though I suppose it gets much less attention in this era of copious memories). Migrating to Stack Overflow.

Comment: One word: Rely on virtual memory.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

split the file into parts (buffers) that you can sort in-place

then when all buffers are sorted take 2 (or more) at the time and merge them (like [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Use_with_tape_drives)) until there's only 1 buffer remaining which will be the sorted file

Comment: Yes, mergesort is the way to go here. (On the starting block level you can use any algorithm, though.)

Comment: I too had thought of mergesort initially, but wouldn't merging n/2 and n/2 lead to a sorted array of size n? And memory size is the constraint here. So if you sort 2 chunks of 1 GB buffers individually, the merge would consist of 2 GB - which cannot be accomodated in memory.

Comment: @saurabh those buffers are files that you stream so the full buffer doesn't need to be loaded in memory

Comment: @ratchet freak, do you mean, first read a part of the file into a buffer (1 GB) and sort the buffer, then write the sorted buffer back to the file?

Comment: I have to use external merge sorting that is, Move partially sorted data as small chunks of files and do merge sort over. What could be the order of this algorithm? Similar to merge sort? As file read and write is specific to a platform, can we ignore them when calculating order?

Comment: Whereas this works, the binary merge that you propose highly inefficient. Each item is read from and written to disk log2(k) times, where k is the number of blocks. You can instead do a multiway merge, which guarantees that each item is read and written twice: once when being sorted with its block, and once during the merge pass.

Comment: @JimMischel but the binary method will work on any size data. while the multiway merge could run out of memory if the overhead of tracking all streams is too large.

Comment: True. In that case you do multiple multi-way merges, which is still going to be hugely more efficient than the binary merge, unless you're talking a severely memory-restricted machine, in which case your buffers are so small that algorithmic efficiency is completely swamped by I/O time.

Comment: What is the size of each part?

Comment: @Nazmul81 small enough that you can sort in place inside the 1GB given that you need some space to hold your variables you could easily go up to 0.9GB per part

Answer (score 19):

Please see this [link](http://homes.sice.indiana.edu/yye/lab/teaching/spring2014-C343/datatoobig.php). This guy has explained it beautifully.

**An example of disk-based application**:
External mergesort algorithm (wikipedia)
-> *A merge sort divides the unsorted list into **n** sublists, each containing **1** element, and then repeatedly merges sublists to produce new sorted sublists until there is only **1** sublist remaining*.
The external mergesort algorithm sorts chunks that each fit in RAM, then merges the sorted chunks together.

**For example**, for sorting **900** megabytes of data using only **100** megabytes of RAM:

1. Read **100** MB of the data in main memory and sort by some conventional sorting method, like quicksort.
2. Write the sorted data to disk.
3. Repeat steps **1** and **2** until all of the data is in sorted **100** MB chunks (there are 900MB / 100MB = **9** chunks), which now need to be merged into one single output file.
4. Read the first **10** MB of each sorted chunk (of **100** MB) into input buffers in main memory and allocate the remaining **10** MB for an output buffer. (In practice, it might provide better performance to make the output buffer larger and the input buffers slightly smaller.)
5. Perform a **9**-way merge and store the result in the output buffer. Whenever the output buffer fills, write it to the final sorted file and empty it. Whenever any of the **9** input buffers empties, fill it with the next 10 MB of its associated **100** MB sorted chunk until no more data from the chunk is available. This is the key step that makes external merge sort work externally -- because the merge algorithm only makes one pass sequentially through each of the chunks, each chunk does not have to be loaded completely; rather, sequential parts of the chunk can be loaded as needed.

Comment: Link is not working.

Comment: can just remove the code format... scrolling horizontally is a bit difficult to follow

Comment: @Ravi/@aanhlle text is now formatted!

Answer (score 4):

We use merge sort first data divided then merged .

1. Divide the data into 10 groups each of size 1gb.
2. Sort each group and write them to disk.
3. Load 10 items from each group into main memory.
4. Output the smallest item from the main memory to disk. Load the next item from the group whose item was chosen.
5. Loop step #4 until all items are not outputted.

Answer (score 2):

For sorting 10 GB of data using only 1 GB of RAM:

1. Read 1 GB of the data in main memory and sort by using quicksort.
2. Write the sorted data to disk.
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 until all of the data is in sorted 1GB chunks (there are 10 GB / 1 GB = 10 chunks), which now need to be merged into one single output file.
4. Read the first 90 MB of each sorted chunk (of 1 GB) into input buffers in main memory and allocate the remaining 100 MB for an output buffer. 
   (For better performance, we can take the output buffer larger and the input buffers slightly smaller.)
5. Perform a 10-way merge and store the result in the output buffer.
6. Whenever the output buffer fills, write it to the final sorted file and empty it. 
   Whenever any of the 90 MB input buffers empty, fill it with the next 90 MB of its associated 1 GB sorted chunk until no more data from the chunk is available.

This is the external merge sort approach which works externally.

Comment: What, ignoring a factor of 10, does this answer add to the information hyperlinked in [Vivek Garg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52365611/3789665) or the accepted one? It has become regrettably commonplace to ignore things like *generating the least amount of runs feasible* or *leave a bit of inversions for each merge to clean up* (if memory serves, Knuth addresses both).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Split the file into 10 chunks of 1GB, sort them in memory and store into disk

Step 2: Use a min heap and store first element of each sorted chunk along with it's chunk number, poll the minimum and stream to a new disk location, insert the next number of the polled number's chunk and repeat Step 2 until all elements are parsed and heap becomes empty

Answer (score 0):

To sort an array, you can first sort the first two thirds, then the last two thirds and finally the first two thirds. So on the first pass, the largest n/3 numbers are guaranteed to be in the last two thirds (either sorted by the first pass or already present) and after the second pass the smallest are in the first two thirds, with the final pass sorting the array entirely. Using recursion, you can repeat this pattern down until the 'two thirds' are small enough to fit in RAM.

Comment: Please try to add an assessment of time needed where only one tenth of the data fits into RAM.